# ZipInputStream not working with request.getInputStream()

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, zip

I am sending a zip file to a server over post method and at server a servlet is used to retrieved its contents and display. The zip contains only one txt file. I am setting entity as following on client side

```
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
entity.addPart("string", new FileBody(file, "application/zip"));
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
```

In the servlet when i use 
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(request.getInputStream());
it does not work. Why??

Comment: You are not sending just the zip file, it's wrapped in a MultipartEntity. You need to decode that first. Or if you control both client and server, stop doing Multipart and post the raw file.

Comment: I have control only at server side @Thilo

Comment: You're sending a `multipart/form-data` request. The duplicate shows how to deal with `multipart/form-data` requests in a servlet (just ignore the HTML form snippet and substitute it with your Java based client).

Comment: The client side code is not using jsp. Its uses simple .java file to send data to server @BalusC

Comment: In particular, once you get to `InputStream fileContent = filePart.getInputStream();` you can retrieve the zipped data.

Comment: i tried adding the following line Part p=request.getPart("string"); It gives error and neither it goes further when ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(request.getInputStream()); is encountered

Comment: LZW is a block (and not a streaming) compressor.

Comment: BalusC, i read all the text written there please suggest by writing some code in the comments.